# Python If Condition with two conditions dependent on a tuple

Tags: python, ruby, conditional-statements, tuples, python-2.7

I have only recently begun programming in Python (with previous Ruby experience). I am trying to set up an if condition with two conditions:

```
if not previous[1] and previous[0][0] == 5:
            print "hello world"
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>: tuple index out of range
```

Print previous returns: `((5, 1, 9, 23),)`

What am I doing wrong?

I am looking for something similar to they Ruby Syntax: `unless previous[1]`

Comment: Your `previous` print has mismatched parentheses. Did you perhaps copy it wrong?

Comment: I did, I just changed it

Comment: Why wrapping a tuple inside 1-tuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`((5, 1, 9, 23),)`, then this is a length-1 tuple. It's only element--with index 0--is the tuple `(5, 1, 9, 23)`. It doesn't have a second element to have the index `1`, so `that_tuple[1]` raises `IndexError`.

What did you hope `previous[1]` would give you?

Comment: So if I want to test for the existence of previous[1], what would be the proper syntax?

Comment: @Spencer, `if len(previous) > 1` will test that, but I'm concerned that might not be what you need to be dealing with. What were you checking it for? *What did you expect `previous[1]` to be when you wrote the code?* Were you originally trying to check for existence?

Comment: In some cases, I expect it to be another tuple, in other cases I expect it not to exist. This tuple is returned from a database call, and I want to handle instances with two returned rows differently than instances with one returned row.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a single element in '`previous`'. That is why you are getting an `IndexError` when you attempt to retrieve element 1.

Comment: how would I test for existence of previous[1]?

Comment: You can use len(previous) to determine the number of elements in previous.

Answer (score 0):

Your index error is coming from `previous[1]` - previous is 1-tuple ... you'd need `previous[0]` and `previous[0][0]`.

Comment: how would I test for existence of previous[1]?